# An Error Occurred: Syntax Error: Unexpected token y

Tags: mysql, json, jersey

I don't know why I am getting this. Here is some of the code where I try to retrieve some information from database and send it as response to a Jersey resource mapped to a certain URL. I don't know what that y is theerror referring to:

```
public String myInformation(String theName){

        String infoQuery = "Select * from bookinfo where name= \'theName\'";
        ResultSet result = null;
        conn = newConnection.dbConnection();

        try
        {   

            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(infoQuery);
            result = preparedStatement.executeQuery(infoQuery);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuilder information = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            if(result != null){
                while(result.next()){

               // Build the string which is returned from this
              // method and sent as json response for a URL of a resource

             I read columns from database and use StringBuilder to store it.                          At the end I convert it to String and pass it to Jersey resource. 
           }

else{
                System.out.println("No result");
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String someInformation = information.toString();
        return someInformation;
}
```

In my resource:

```
@GET
    @Path("/allSome/{theName}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getSomeInfo(@PathParam("theName") String theName){

        System.out.println("Name is: "+ theName);
        BookInformation bookInfo = new BookInformation();
        String bookInformation =bookInfo.bookInformation(bookName);

        ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.status(Status.OK);
        responseBuilder.entity(bookInformation);

        Response response = responseBuilder.build();
        return response;
    }
```

**Edit**

My method is returning a String. On Postman client and I am receiving data back from database but it is coming back as a string with no spaces between them. I think I need to convert that string to JSON so that my resource can send it back to client for displaying on page.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post more code, for instance where this code is being called from, and you're full error message?

Answer (score 0):

The 'y' must be in the `theName` parameter, along with some quotes. You should be using `PreparedStatement` properly, with a placeholder parameter:

```
String infoQuery = "Select * from bookinfo where name = ?";
// ...
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(infoQuery);
preparedStatement.setString(1, theName);
// ...
```

Your code is poorly structured. Code that depends on the success of a try block should be inside the try block.

Comment: I will still need to use escape characters though I think in order for the query to work. I did try to do the above solution, but was getting error, "Unexpected end of input. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1".. That is why I was trying to put the actual term for querying and checking how to get around these escape sequences. Now I am back with the same error.

Comment: I dont think escape character were needed. My JavaScript was able to make progress though. Error was in the part that I had set data-type in Ajax call to JSON although I was receiving text. But  the error persists at the part where String infoQuery is defined. It gives the error now "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1".